# Ruby - Hacker Rank issue

Tags: arrays, ruby, loops

**

Ok guys , i have a problem with a task in Hacker Rank.
I can't pass all tests.

---

**

The task:

Given five positive integers, find the minimum and maximum values that can be calculated by summing exactly four of the five integers. Then print the respective minimum and maximum values as a single line of two space-separated long integers.

Function Description

Complete the miniMaxSum function in the editor below.

miniMaxSum has the following parameter(s):

arr: an array of 5 integers

Print

Print two space-separated integers on one line: the minimum sum and the maximum sum of 4 of 5 elements.

Input Format

A single line of five space-separated integers.

**That is the task and my code: **

```
require 'json'
require 'stringio'

#
# Complete the 'miniMaxSum' function below.
#
# The function accepts INTEGER_ARRAY arr as parameter.
#

def miniMaxSum(arr)
   if arr[0] != arr[1]
     $prev = 0 
     $prev2 = Float::INFINITY
     i = 0
     5.times do
       $res = arr.reject { |n| n == arr[i] }.sum
       $prev = $res if $res > $prev
       i = i + 1
      end
      i = 0
     5.times do
       $res2 = arr.reject { |n| n == arr[i] }.sum
       $prev2 = $res2 if $res < $prev2
       i = i + 1
      end
     print "#{$prev2} #{$prev}"
    else
        print "#{arr.sum} #{arr.sum}"
    end
      
end

arr = gets.rstrip.split.map(&:to_i)

miniMaxSum arr
```

PLEASE HELP.

Comment: Sum all 5 integers *once*, then subtract each integer from the sum.

Comment: "I can't pass all tests" – Please, show the tests, and show which ones you are passing and which ones you are failing, and include the *precise* error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can observe that the sum of 4 of the 5 elements is simply the sum of all 5 minus one of the elements. If we have `[1,2,3,4,5]` the sum is 15 and we can get the partial sums by subtracting each from that. 15 - 1 is 14, 15 - 2 is 13, and so on.

Then we can find the min and the max in a single loop.

This is *algorithmically* more efficient than sorting and summing the largest and the smallest numbers. This algorithm only has to iterate through the list twice. It runs in 2n time, or O(n). Sorting requires O(nlogn) plus two iterations to sum. This doesn't matter for 5 numbers, but it's very important as the size gets larger.

See [Time Complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity).

```
def min_max_sum(nums)
  # Take the sum of every number.
  sum = nums.sum

  # Ye olde min/max trick.
  # Set min to something everything will be smaller than.
  # Set max to something everything will be larger than.
  min = Float::INFINITY
  max = -Float::INFINITY
  
  # For each number...
  nums.each do |num|
    # Get the sum for 4 of 5 values by subtracting this number from the sum.
    partial_sum = sum - num
    
    # Check if it's the min and/or the max.
    min = partial_sum if partial_sum < min
    max = partial_sum if partial_sum > max
  end
  
  return [min, max]
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't it be enough to sum the 4 smallest and the 4 biggest elements in the array?

Your question is a bit unclear about in input, therefore I provide two answers.

When the input is an *array of 5 integers*:

```
def min_max_sum(array)
  sorted = array.sort
  puts "#{sorted.first(4).sum}  #{sorted.last(4).sum}"
end

min_max_sum [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
#=> 10  14
```

When the input format is *a single line of five space-separated integers*:

```
def min_max_sum(string)
  sorted = string.split(/ /).map(&:to_i).sort
  puts "#{sorted.first(4).sum}  #{sorted.last(4).sum}"
end

min_max_sum "5 4 3 2 1"
#=> 10  14
```

Comment: After I created an each_with_index monstrosity that mostly worked, but was shamefully ugly, I came across this simple and truly elegant solution. It's yet another example how it pays off to take an extra minute or two to really understand what a problem is asking for instead of jumping straight into writing code, and that not every problem requires a complex and convoluted solution.